# Trying to connect to iTunes store when app is not in app store

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, app-store

While running application when it tries to connect to iTunes it shows alert `"Cannot connect to iTunes store"`. 
I tried various things assuming it as a bug. But now I wonder whether it is because application is not in app store. I also searched to see if I check if it is because app is not in apple store, but no result giving my answer. Now,  I think I need to ask this question here even though it is so simple.
Am I right about app not in apple store or is it really a bug?

Comment: When / how / for what => show us some code if possible

Comment: @Daij-Djan I use appirater library https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater to prompt rating alert to screen and if user clicks on `rate` then it will connect to iTunes store to open app and user can rate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you said try to open the app's page in iTunes store / app store...
but since your app isn't there, the App Store can't find the requested page.

no bug at all